# Run asynchronous code inside backgroundworker

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, backgroundworker

I found a few examples on the internet but I'm having a hard time trying to run my async call inside a background worker. I'm working in WP8. What's missing?

Edit: The purpose of this is to update the values I'm reading from time to time. Let's say 1s.

Here is my async code, it just gets and stores some data in providers []:

```
public void getAllProvidersMethod()
        {
            try
            {
                sc.getAllProvidersCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.getAllProvidersCompletedEventArgs>(callback);
                sc.getAllProvidersAsync();
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }

public void callback(object sender, ServiceReference1.getAllProvidersCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                providers = new String[e.Result.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < e.Result.Length; i++)
                {
                    providers[i] = e.Result[i].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception d)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(d.ToString());
            }
        }
```

This is my background worker:

```
private void networkWorker()
        {
            var obj = App.Current as App;
            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
        delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            BackgroundWorker b = o as BackgroundWorker;

                getAllProvidersMethod();

        });

            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        delegate(object o, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" ");
        });

            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using a BGW at all if your operation is asynchronous?  The primary purpose of a BGW is for long running *CPU bound* work.  Since the method you're using won't block the UI thread just execute it directly from the UI thread.

Comment: @Servy Yes but I want to update the values I'm reading from time to time. Let's say 1s. So I thought about placing it in a background worker. Is it possible? Or there is another way?

Comment: You won't want to use a BGW here.  It just isn't designed to help you do this.  You may be able to do whatever you want, but you haven't told us what you actually want to do with this async method that you currently can't.  Odds are, if it's possible, it won't be leveraging a BGW to do it.

Comment: It looks like `sc` is a generated proxy for some service. As such, there's not really a good way to show "progress" for the call (unless the service includes a "query in-flight call status" method; most do not.) As Servy said, just call it from your main thread; you can just show an indeterminate progress bar until the call completes.

Comment: @Servy So there is no way of having my async code runing from time to time? I don't know if you are understanding what I want but imagine this as a reader and I want to leave it reading automatically from time to time.

Comment: @sparcopt I have no idea how you intend to run this code "from time to time".  You start it, it calls the callback when it's done, and that's it.  Do you want to periodically restart it?  If so, use a `Timer`.

Comment: @Servy Maybe restarting will do what I want, I will do some searching about Timer, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to get it working!

For anyone that wants to run some async code automatically from time to time, forget about backgroundworkers, what you are looking for is a Timer. 
Thank you Servy for the Timer hint.

Let's say I want to call `asyncCall` for each 5 seconds.

It's very simple. First define how long is your wait time between calls (how long you want it to wait before calling the same code again).

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 5000); // HERE - for example 5000 is 5 seconds
dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
dt.Start();
```

And then all you need is to write the code you want to repeat inside this method:

```
void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            asyncCall();
}
```

In this case for each 5 seconds it will call `asyncCall`.